# Are there any good oracle podcasts?

Tags: oracle, podcast

Are there any good oracle podcasts around? The only ones I've found is produced by oracle corp, and as such are little more than advertising pieces pushing their technology of the moment.

I'm specifically interested in Database technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Oracle Podcast Center

---

[Green Enterprise Podcasts](http://www.oracle.com/applications/podcasts-sustainability.html)

Host: Paul Salinger, VP Marketing

Listen to discussions with customers, partners, and Oracle green experts, exploring topics that can help Oracle customers better understand how Oracle products can support their sustainability initiatives and enable a green enterprise.

---

[Oracle AppCasts](http://www.oracle.com/customers/cust_successcasts.html)

*Host: Cliff Godwin, SVP, Applications Technology*

Tune into "Live with Cliff" to hear from application technology experts, product and industry experts, and customers about what's saving Oracle customers time and money when using Oracle E-Business Suite, PeopleSoft, and JD Edwards applications.

---

[Oracle Customer SuccessCasts](http://www.oracle.com/customers/cust_successcasts.html)

Tune into Oracle Customer SuccessCasts, where customers describe how Oracle helps them to run their businesses more successfully.

---

[Oracle Database Podcasts](http://www.oracle.com/database/podcasts.html)

Tune into this podcast series to get the latest information on Oracle Database from Oracle technical experts.

---

[Oracle Fusion Middleware Radio](http://www.oracle.com/products/middleware/ofmradio.html)

*Host: Rick Schultz, VP, Product Marketing for Oracle Fusion Middleware & Security Products*

Tune into this podcast series about Oracle Fusion Middleware to hear about Oracle's middleware product strategy and explore what middleware means to your business—growth, agility, insight, and reduced risk.

---

[Oracle Magazine Feature Casts](http://www.oracle.com/technology/syndication/magcasts/index.html)

Tune into conversations with Oracle Magazine editors, authors, and Oracle subject matter experts about featured articles in Oracle Magazine. Go beyond print with additional insight into Oracle products, technologies, customers, and more.

---

[Oracle PartnerNetwork (OPN) PartnerCast](http://www.oracle.com/partners/home/news/global/auth/opn-partnercasts.html)

Tune in and learn how to grow your business with Oracle, exclusively for Oracle PartnerNetwork members.

---

[Oracle Technology Network Arch2Arch Podcast](http://www.oracle.com/technology/syndication/arch2arch-podcasts/index.html)

*Host: Bob Rhubart, Manager, Architect Community, OTN*

Listen in as architects and other experts from across the Oracle community discuss the topics, tools, and technologies that drive the evolution of software architecture.

---

[Oracle Technology Network TechCasts](http://www.oracle.com/technology/syndication/techcasts/index.html)

*Host: Justin Kestelyn, OTN Editor-in-Chief*

Tune into "fireside chats" with experts about new tools, technologies, and trends in application development.

---

[Oracle@Work](http://feeds.feedburner.com/Oraclework)

Through Oracle@Work Video Podcasts you'll learn how Oracle customers from aerospace and automotive to travel and television address business and technical issues with the latest Oracle technology and applications solutions. Oracle@Works play like short television news magazine pieces shot on location, world wide. See Oracle customers in action, first hand, with Oracle@Work Video Podcasts.

---

[Profit Online Executive Briefing Audiocasts](http://www.oracle.com/profit/audiocasts.html)

Every month, Profit Online presents conversations with Oracle executives, customers, and partners, discussing developments in their businesses and trends in their industries. Tune into and stay up to date on how IT and business leaders are expanding into new markets, improving business processes, and creating the future of the enterprise.

---

*Reference: [Oracle Podcasts](http://www.oracle.com/podcasts/index.html)*

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list: http://www.oracle.com/podcasts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Asking for an "Oracle podcast" that isn't going to be a product marketing focused is too broad. It's almost like asking for a "Microsoft Podcast." Anything you get is going to be broad and shallow. An introduction, nothing in depth.

What are you looking for? DB, Middleware, Linux/OS, ERP, CRM, BI, Information Security, Identify Management, Integration, PL/SQL etc. . . . For what kind of audience? Developer, Sysadmin, DBA, Apps DBA (very diff believe it or not), Technology Manager, Accountant, Finance Director, White Hat security specialist, etc.

Comment: Fair comment, I have updated the query slightly. Although, I haven't been able to find many non Oracle corp endorsed podcasts of any Oracle technology.